# Android Room Create View Bug

Tags: android, android-room

My current Android application employs Room for its local database.
The App has a number of tables and a single view.

The issue I have is that occasionally when I reinstall the application from "scratch" I get the following exception:-

```
2020-04-17 14:20:22.568 20752-20886/org.my.application E/SQLiteLog: (1) table `myView` already exists
```

I believe this issue is caused by Room

For example the table/index create/drop statements are as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
```

where as the View create statement is

```
CREATE VIEW `myView`
```

Why cant Room generate a create view statement which includes `IF NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: where do you put that statement in code. table creation is being handled by room automatically.

Comment: @example, exactly thats not my code, thats the code generated by ROOM. My question is now, Why cant room create a view with the IF NOT EXISTS content?, seems like a bug in Room

Comment: try to put only table in a database. check if it works ?

Comment: @example, TABLES do not give any issue, only views

Comment: weird, could you add your code.  have you used the following docs? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/creating-views are you getting an exception or just a warning? i think the db shouldt even be recreated unless you totally unintsall your app before reinstallation

Comment: @quealegriamasalegre, yes thats the docs I followed, Im using Koin to inject my database and I think its that approach thats exposing this bug in Room. It looks to me like a simple oversight by the Room developers, why could'nt they add IF NOT EXISTS to all view creation statements

Comment: maybe it is indeed it seems that views have only been supported sinse recently

Answer (score 1):

The thing is such behavior is intentional, due to the platform and `@DatabaseView` Room annotation usecases.

The annotation main target is `class`. Default name of `@DatabaseView` is name of that class. Room cannot forbid you to create classes with the same name because it is not its domain of responsibility(and it is hardly possible).

Now let us imagine that `IF NOT EXISTS` is present in view creation query. We have two classes with the same name that define Room view. We have no control over which view is created when, thus we won't know which view will we have in our database under specific name, because there won't be any warning regarding view overriding. It would be very bug-prone and confusing if such a behavior existed.

We can define custom name for the view, but it may be the same as class name of some other view that already exists which will cause the same problems.

In table creation we have this `IF NOT EXISTS` clause because we have all the control regarding naming, creating and linking this table to our database. For tables we do it explicitly while for views implicitly.

Remember that Room implements only a limited subset of SQLite functions. To have more control over what you want to achieve - use SQLite directly.

I believe, the problems stated above in my answer, are the main reason for such a behavior of Room implementation of SQLite views. Keep in mind that in future something may change, though, so this answer might be relevant only for some time.

Hope it helps.